# Can we make an alluvial plot in R to display multiple bivariate distributions instead of the full multivariate distribution?

Tags: r, visualization, categorical-data

I want to display multiple bivariate distribution in R instead of the full multivariate distribution.
The following code provided in the [vignette of the alluvial package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alluvial/vignettes/alluvial.html) uses an alluvial plot to display the full multivariate distribution of (Class, Sex, Age, Survived) for the Titanic dataset.

```
require(dplyr)
require(alluvial)
tit <- as.data.frame(Titanic, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(tit)
alluvial(tit[,1:4], freq=tit$Freq,
     col = ifelse(tit$Survived == "Yes", "orange", "grey"),
     border = ifelse(tit$Survived == "Yes", "orange", "grey"),
     hide = tit$Freq == 0,
     cex = 0.7)
```

[image]

Instead of vizualising the full multivariate distribution, I would like to visualise the bivariate distributions (Class,Sex), (Sex,Age), & (Age, Survived) using a single alluvial plot. The count of the three bivariate distributions are

```
tit%>%group_by(Class,Sex)%>%summarize(Freq=sum(Freq))%>%ungroup() 
tit%>%group_by(Sex,Age)%>%summarize(Freq=sum(Freq))%>%ungroup()
tit%>%group_by(Age,Survived)%>%summarize(Freq=sum(Freq))%>%ungroup()
```

**Do you know if it feasible using the *alluvial* package or an alternative one?**

For this particular example, using an alluvial plot might seem dubious. But it fully makes sense when variables are ordered and when we want to visualise bivariate distributions of (var1,var2), (var2,var3),...

Comment: I dont understand you're expected output

Comment: you man this: `tmp <- tit %>% group_by(Class, Sex) %>% summarize(Freq = sum(Freq)) %>% ungroup();alluvial(tmp[1:2], freq = tmp$Freq)` ? for each couple of variables you wrote?

Comment: yes exactly that but with the distributions of (Class,Sex), (Sex,Age), & (Age, Survived) in the same alluvial plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set up three alluvial plots together you can do as follow.

Note that `count` is a `dplyr` more compact version of `group_by` + `summarise` + `ungroup`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(alluvial)

tit <- as.data.frame(Titanic, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

oldpar <- par(mfrow=c(1, 3)) # set up alignment

with(count(tit, Class, Sex     , wt = Freq), alluvial(Class, Sex     , freq = n))
with(count(tit, Sex  , Age     , wt = Freq), alluvial(Sex  , Age     , freq = n))
with(count(tit, Age  , Survived, wt = Freq), alluvial(Age  , Survived, freq = n))

par(oldpar) # reset par
```

[image]

It's a good habit to reset `par` every time you modified it since it's a general option that may affect other parts of your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is great. Even better would have been to remove the duplicate barplots (barplot for sex and barplot for age) but that might be too complex to achieve. Thanks again.